# How to set permissions to IniFile in WiX?

Tags: wix

I have a component with an IniFile element in my WiX script. I need to set the read and write permissions for the Local Service to the resulting ini-file as the application runs under this account and must be able to read and write from/into the ini-file. The Permission(Ex) elements can't have IniFile as a parent so I don't see the native way in WiX to set permissions to an IniFile element, could anyone suggest a solution? The file is installed into a subfolder of CommonAppData.

The option to include a ready ini-file in the distribution and install it simply as a File is bad for me as the contents of the file depends on the individual installation (paths, computer name etc).

Comment: Under the Component element, you will  have both  the <File> as well as the <IniFile> elements nested.  You will have your Permission(ex) element nested under the <File> element.  Have you tried this?

Comment: I've just tried this but the linker looks for the file specified in File/@Name and apparently doesn't find it as the file is only created when the msi package is installed rather than when it is built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Wix are you using? I am using Wix v3.9 and could get it to work. Well, I don't understand why the PermissionEx element would be concerned about the "Name" attribute of the File tab, especially when PermissionEx is itself nested/a child of the File tag.

Here is my sample project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="INIFile" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Test" UpgradeCode="4549f852-c012-4180-ab66-5d972f3faf53">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="INIFile" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="INIFile" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">

     <Component Id="ProductComponent">
   <File Id="TestFile" KeyPath="yes" Source="E:\Learning\Test Projects\Files\test.txt"   Name="test.txt">
     <PermissionEx Id="Blah" Sddl="O-AB-C" />
   </File>
   <IniFile Id="TestIni" Action="addLine" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Key="Test" Name="Test" Section="Test" Value="Test"/>
    </Component> 
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't realize I could install an empty file using a <File> and immediately add entries to it by <IniFile> within the same component. I thought I had to either install a complete ini file by <File> and then somehow process it by Custom Actions or produce the entire file using only <IniFile> elements. So in my comment to my original post I simply set both the <File> and <IniFile> to the same file name without having such a source file in the hope that WiX would figure out what I needed but obviously this was against the installer rules so an error occurred.

Comment: The full comment was too long so here comes the second part to the comment above: can I be sure that multiple elements within a Component are always executed in the order they appear in the WiX file? I've searched but not found a clear answer to this question.

Comment: Each and every element is processed by a particular action within the InstallExecuteSequence table. For example: in the Wix documentation for IniFile tag, there is a section called Windows Installer references . The windows installer references for IniFile tage are  IniFile Table, RemoveIniFile Table . This means that the IniFile tag is connected to IniFile Table, RemoveIniFile Table . Further , reading the MSDN documenation for IniFile table(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369282(v=vs.85).aspx),  there is another comment which says which particular standard action will be invoked

Comment: You will see the following comment:This table is referred to when the WriteIniValues action or the RemoveIniValues action is executed.   So, this means that using the IniFile tag would populate entries in the IniFile table. The entries in the IniFile table are processed in the InstallExecuteSequence table by the WriteIniValues action or the RemoveIniValues action. **The ordering of these  actions in the built msi package have no relation whatsoever to  the order in which you declare the elements in the Wix file**. Their ordering is set by the Wix tool as per the guidelines laid down in the

Comment: windows installer SDK. For a list of suggested sequence numbers, please take a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx.  Ofcourse, you are at liberty to change the sequence numbers of  these standard actions but it is not recommended if you are not really sure of what you are doing. To see the sequence numbers assigned in the final built msi package, open the built msi package using the windows installer editor called Orca. Orca is part of the windows instaler SDK. Once opened, inspect the sequence numbers in the InstallExecuteSequence table.

Comment: I was concerned that writing ini entries could happen before the source file was copied to the target system by the <File> element but going through your comments I see that the InstallFiles action is normally scheduled earlier than WriteIniValues so my worries are groundless. Thank you, I will use your suggestion and mark your post as the answer.